# tkinter: Pressing spacebar activates last-used button, even if it's no longer on the screen

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a button that, when pressed, changes the page by degridding its parent frame and gridding new frames. However, if the user hits space after this button is pressed, it runs the button's command again because the button is still highlighted/selected even though it is no longer visible. This presents some big problems for my code which depends on this button only being pressed once. How can I "clear" the highlighting of a button or at least disable the spacebar from being used to activate buttons?

Comment: You can change the focus to some other widget using `<widget>.focus_set()` after the function has completed its task.

Comment: Make setting the focus — via `focus_set()` — to a some widget part of the changing the page process. Also note you can disable a button by setting its `state` option to `tk.DISABLED` (and activate one by setting it to the value `tk.ACTIVE`).